# How to hide formulas in excel 2016?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to hide the formula of a cell (from the function bar) if there are no values to calculate.

For example:

The function is in E3, using the values of C3 and D3. But if those two cells are empty, or only one of them is empty, then E3 will show a number still (because the type of formula I used), how can it be blank, or at least show a dash when one or both cells are empty?

Comment: `IF(OR(C3="",D3=""),"",<yourformula>)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: You may use `=IF(AND(C3<>"",D3<>""),<your formula here>,"")`

Comment: I appreciate this other option as well!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your formula in an `IF` statement that checks if either cell is blank:

```
 IF(OR(C3="",D3=""),"",<yourformula>)
```

Comment: by any chance, do you know how could I hide the formula also (from the function bar)?

Comment: Hide the function bar itself (in the "View" tab)