# Blank function bar

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I used a function to show the result of a calculation, but is it possible to hide such function from the function bar?

Example:

I used C4 and D4 to get the result on E4, when I click on E4, I see the huge formula in the function bar. Can this be hidden? If so, how?

I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide formulas in excel 2016?](https://superuser.com/questions/1503151/how-to-hide-formulas-in-excel-2016)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Follow these steps:*

- Select the cell `E4`, or range of cells where you want to hide formula/formulas.
- **R**ight click and select **F**ormat cells option from the menu.
- Hit **P**rotection TAB.
- **P**rotection TAB has two **C**heck boxes to mark, **L**ocked &  **H**idden.
- Check both and finish with **O**k.
- Finally **C**lick the **R**eview TAB then **P**rotect Sheet.
- Write Password and finish with **O**k

*Remember the Password is case sensitive.*

**N.B.**

- **L**ocked option restricts editing and **H**idden hides formula from the formula bar.
- The **P**assword protection restricts the user to unlock sheet, unless the correct Password is not written, as well hides the formula from **F**ormula Bar.

Comment: Great, all done, thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you @stardust,, keep asking ☺